# Problema con Include de PHP y Tab de Bootstrap 4x

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

Estoy desarrollando una web con bootstrap 4.3. Todo perfecto. 
El problema es que tengo una página con un tab vertical y dentro del contenido de cada tab, se incluye un include() que muestra la información de uno u otro archivo.

- Cuando hago clic en el primer tab, se muestra correctamente el include del primer tab.
- Cuando hago clic en cualquier otro tab, se muestra el contenido del primer tab y más abajo el contenido del tab clicleado.

Cómo hacer para que no se muestre, en los otros tabs, el contenido del primer tab?

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-empleos-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-empleos" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-empleos" aria-selected="true">Empleos</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-candidatos-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-candidatos" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-candidatos" aria-selected="false">Candidatos</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-agregar-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-agregar" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-agregar" aria-selected="false">Agregar</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-perfil-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-perfil" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-perfil" aria-selected="false">Perfil</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-empleos" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-empleos-tab">
          <?php include_once('empresa-listado-empleos.php'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-candidatos" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-candidatos-tab">
          <?php include('empresa-listado-candidatos.php'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-agregar" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-agregar-tab">
          <?php include('empresa-agregar-empleos.php'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-perfil" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-perfil-tab">
          <?php include('empresa-perfil.php'); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Las llamadas a bootstrap, se incluyen correctamente conforme el manual de Bootstrap 4x.

Comment: Estoy casi seguro que el problema es del include y no de tu codificación de Bootstrap, más exactamente en la clase `active` que es la que muestra el contenido del tab. Tuve un inconveniente similar hace un tiempo, puedes revisar [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34491781/9609518) y nos avisas cómo te va.

Comment: Hola, @Mario Campos Por favor incluye también lo que contienen los archivos que incluyes o en su defecto conocer el código final que te muestra el navegador, ya que es muy relativa tu pregunta y pueden ser muchas cosas.